# Stack Overflow e o Código-Fonte

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

Boa tarde! Sou novo aqui, e sou estudante de Sistemas de Informação. Apresentarei um trabalho sobre o Stack Overflow, e gostaria de saber qual a relação existente entre o Stack Overflow e o compartilhamento de códigos-fonte. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Breno, creio que não há compartilhamento de código fonte, mas de conhecimento.

Comment: Comece por [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ..... Não compartilhamos código fonte apenas partes para facilitar o entendimento do erro e da resposta...

Comment: Como assim "qual a relação"? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Este tipo de perguntas relacionadas com o site, devem ser feitas no [Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com) e não no site principal. No entanto mesmo assim deveriam ser adicionadas mais informações à pergunta, pois assim como ela está no momento, está bastante vaga. As respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser respostas de apenas 1 ou 2 palavras como - "Não, não existe compartilhamento". Mas no entanto não quer dizer que seja proibido. Tente aprimorar a sua pergunta.

Comment: Se entendi direito o mais próximo disso deve ser o termo legal, sobre quem é dono da publicação e como deve ser feita a citação daquele conteudo.

Comment: O StackOverflow é bem grandinho. Você está apenas na pequenina parte que está em português, que é menos de 1% do todo. Há uma comunidade em inglês agregada a rede do StackOverflow (que tem mais de 130 comunidades no total) chamada Code Review que está mais próxima do propósito de compartilhar código-fonte, embora não seja ainda isso. Vale a pena dar uma olhada lá também: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Essa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3749/91) explica melhor o que citei no comentário anterior. Se não for isso edite a pergunta e adicione novos detalhes e bem vindo :D

Comment: Deixa eu ver o quanto eu **não** entendi a sua pergunta... A sua questão é jurídica? Você quer saber se os programadores que contribuem com o site ainda detém os direitos autorais sobre os códigos postados? ;)

Comment: Se o objetivo do seu trabalho é falar sobre código-livre, o SO não é o melhor exemplo. Uma plataforma interessante para se falar seria o Github, que facilita a publicação, compartilhamento e colaboração de código.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi a pergunta, esta um pouco confusa, me parece que talvez você não tenha entendido o StackOverflow. De qualquer maneira a relação de "compartilhamento de código" (ou qualquer conteúdo) é sob a licensa **cc by-sa 3.0**, que permite *compartilhar, copiar, redistribuir, editar, modificar e criar sob o material aqui, para qualquer proposito, inclusive comercial* como dito na resposta do [@OnoSendai](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4527/3635)

Answer (score 13):

Todo e qualquer conteúdo postado no Stack Overflow será sujeito à licença Creative Commons.

No rodapé de todas as páginas existe a seguinte menção:

> User contributions licensed under **cc by-sa 3.0** with **attribution required**.